# i want to start an activity/ app itself on onMessageReceived (FCM) when the App is not running in Android

Tags: android

On push message receive i want to start an activity / app itself on onMessageReceived (FCM) when the App is not running. How to start activity when onMessageReceived fired. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Um, to start an activity, call `startActivity()`. Note that the user may not appreciate you interrupting them in the middle of whatever they are doing. Please consider raising a `Notification` instead.

Comment: what you are trying is not a good approach. You can choose to start your activity on click of the notification that is received.

Comment: Yes but i need to develop an app when notification received i need to start an activity like incoming call which will be my custom activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should send data payload in your FCM message. Data payload gets received in on message method irrespective of your app being in foreground or background. Handle the action there. Like show notification by reading the data payload always, or if you want show an alert dialog when your app is open or in the foreground.

here is a sample payload:

```
{
  "to": "registration_id_or_topic",
  "data": {
        "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
        "youtubeURL": "https://youtu.be/A1SDBIViRtE"
   }
}
```

Then in your onMessageReceived:

```
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
//Create or Start Your New Activity.
       }
    }
```

Comment: its working fine when app is in forground but a activity not start after receiving message when the app is in close state.